# Link in the body of notification

Tags: lightning, chatter

**Question :** Is it possible to embed direct link in the body of the notification?

I am using chatter ConnectAPI to send notification.

[image]

I tried to add the link by using ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput but what happens there is that the link gets added but user has to click the notification and on detail page the link appears. So basically user has to click 2 times which could have been solved if the link could have been embedded in body itself.

If there are any pointers please help.

Answer (score 0):

The notification will direct the user to the record set in the target id variable, trying nullifying it by 000000000000000AAA.